# Why can't define get type and set type distinctly within Properties?

Tags: vb.net, properties

Here is the problem, I wanted to define a property which accepts `decimal` numbers and do some  process on the value and return `string` such as the below:

```
Public Property Amount() As String
    Get
        Return Utility.PaddingRight(Me.msAmount.ToString(), 10)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal vsValue As Decimal)
        Me.msAmount = vsValue
    End Set
End Property
```

But compilers warns "Set parameters must have the same type of the containing property."

It doesn't look like it should throws an error since it looks legit.

Comment: Except it isn't 'legit' because it is wrong and completely against the language specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you can't is because what you put into a property should be exactly the same as what you get out of it. If the type changed then this condition would never be true. [Microsoft's spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt.aspx) says that "Properties are like smart fields". Imagine if a field (class variable) changed between reading and writing.

Your goal is completely valid but that's not the intended use for properties. (By "intended goal" I mean Microsoft's intended goal.) Your design would also opens doors for potential problems if an invalid or null string were passed in. One of the design goals for properties is that they are light weight and shouldn't throw errors. They ***can*** but ***shouldn't***. The recommended solution is to use the `TryParse` pattern for your property.

**EDIT**

Sorry, my brain was sidetracked, your goal is changing the getter, not the setter. The pattern that you're looking for is just a read-only property (as @msarchet pointed out) that's specific to your getter. For instance, `AmountForPrint` or something. You should still include a read/write for your actual value, too.

```
Public ReadOnly Property AmountForPrint
    Get
        Return Me.Amount.ToString()
    End Get
End Property
Public Property Amount As Integer
    Get

    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)

    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a to do this with a method not a property

```
Public Function Amount(ByVal value As Decimal) As String

End Function
```

Comment: Yeah but I am wondering why I am not allowed to this with `Properties`. Why didn't Microsoft let us do that?

Comment: A property is similiar to a declaring a public member variable.  It just gives you a wrapper around the variable access to allow you to put additional code.  But from outside the object, to callers, it looks like a variable and a variable cannot be both a string and a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark . . .

```
Set(ByVal vsValue As String)
    Me.msAmount = System.Convert.ToDecimal(vsValue)
End Set
```

Comment: It is not something I really want. I want to accept only `decimal` numbers and encapsulate what's happening to this value inside of my class.

Comment: This is probably serious overkill, but you could look into [Type Converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx#Y3895)

Answer (score 0):

You'd be far better off doing this as such

```
Public Read Only Property Amount() As String
    Get
         Return Utility.PaddingRight(Me.msAmount.ToString(), 10)
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub SetAmount(ByVal value As Decimal)
    Me.msAmount = value
End Sub
```